# Increasing the parallelism of a periodically running lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that runs every 5 minutes. However, it may occasionally need to handle processing that can take a few seconds, and my application, up to a certain point, can be considered critical and does not tolerate long delays.

I would like to know if there is a way, or if by default AWS Lambda already does this, to initialize another lambda function in parallel when the current one takes longer than usual.

Context: My application will scan the DynamoDB to search for pending events, and then I will send them to an SNS topic to trigger other lambda functions in parallel.

Comment: You might enjoy reading this series of articles: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/) It explains how Lambda creates multiple _containers_ that allows Lambda functions to run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If a request is being processed and another is received an additional execution environment will automatically be spun up to handle this request.This is one of the big advantages of the serverless model, it handles alot of the complexity of horizontal scaling. One thing to watch out for however is cold starts. This happens when a new lambda execution environment is initialised, which results in a delay in the first request as some time is required to provision the new execution environment. There are few things you  can do to mitigate cold starts if they are a problem such as provisioning concurrency https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/provisioned-concurrency.html